# EntityFramework db context picks us wrong connection string in Azure WebJob

Tags: entity-framework, azure, configuration, azure-webjobs

I have a DbContext class in a shared DAL layer which is used both by a WebSite and its associated WebJob. I want both the WebSite and the WebJob to use some shared connection string. For the WebSite, I use publish profiles and Web.config transformations. However, it doesn't seem to be picked up by the WebJob.

What is the best solution to solve this?

Comment: Try adding the connection string to the app.config in the DAL layer. You could also try adding the connection string to the AWS configuration in which the application is hosted.

Comment: How do you pick configuration items?

Comment: Did you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the connection strings you are using in the management portal for the website.
These connection strings will be available for both your website and your WebJobs.

Comment: How to get solution explorer connection string in webjobs class library ?

Comment: IM getting `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

Comment: check your connection string either its incorrect or the sql server is not whitelisting your website.